# How would you create a clothing size db structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

I need to design a structure for clothing sizes on an e-commerce site.
We are using mysql

For now, we have something like this:

```
product(product_id, name, size_id)  
(12, 'formal shoes', 2)  
(224, 'pants', 16)  

size(size_id, gender, category_id)  
(2, 'm', 5)  
(16, 'm', 8)  
(17, 'm', 8)  
(18, 'm', 8)  

category(category_id, category_name)  
(5, 'shoes'),  
(8, 'pants')

size_chart(size_id, country_code, value)  
(2, 'US', '7')  
(2, 'UK', '5')  
(16, 'US', '33w34l')  
(17, 'US', '33w32l')  
(18, 'US', '33')  
(16, 'EU', '48')  
(17, 'EU', '48')  
(18, 'EU', '48')
```

Now, as you can see the problem is that EU 48 has 3 US equivalents (and they're different in the US), so it would be a mess to sort/filter based on a EU input size.
I noticed that many online shops got this wrong and they either leave the conversion to the user or simply list every single international size for search/filters.

So, for example, if the user search for US 33w34l pants, I'd like to show him pants where size_id is 16,17 or 18.

How would you structure everything?

Comment: Yeah, but are those pants all actually the same size?  I mean, if he's searching for '33w34l' pants, wouldn't he be a little surprised to find pants that are '33w32l' in there too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give a physical size an id, and then have a list of sizes and countries which match that actual physical size.. so

(random data bears no resemblance to reality)

```
SizeID 1 = 
country US  size = 33w 41l
country UK size 16
country uk size 18

SizeID 2 = 
country US size = 34w 41l
country UK size 18
country EU size 14
```

then which ever country they are in, they pick their size, and then you can search for all items with that sizeID.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't understand the difference with my example and how would it solve my problem... Thank you

Comment: Because, if I said I waned size 18 UK, you know thats sizeID 1 & 2, you can then pick any other item that matches that code. Eg select * from sizes left join items on sizes.sizeid=items.sizeid where sizes.tag = "{data}" - out pops your items

Comment: Hm, changing your example a little:
SizeID 1 =  
country US  size = 32w 34l  
country UK size 18  
country EU size 16
  
SizeID 2 =  
country US size = 32w 32l  
country UK size 18  
country EU size 14

If someone from UK chooses UK size 18, then you can show him products that have size_id=1 or 2. This is fine.
If someone from the US chooses US size 32w 34l, then he will only see products with size_id=1. This would be wrong, since a UK shop could add an item size 18 and we wouldn't know if it's a id 1 or 2....

Comment: Any country who has sizes that fall into 2 bands, is daft, but, it would work as adding size 18 from my example, would answer to a size 1 or a size 2.. there is only 1 size 18 after all.. (and if you buy clothes here, I can assure you, an 18 can be smaller than a 14 and bigger than a 22 on the same darn rack!)